# Etymology of 制 zhì = make, manufacture

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

What is the etymology of 制? how the meaning is evolved to Make, manufacture?

Ox + hand kerchief + knife becomes Make or Manufacture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

制 has no ox/bull or cloth. That left component is a corrupted version of 未. 未 is a tree with many branches, ready to be chopped down. There is  as a variant form. Original meaning is "cut" hence the knife component 刀 on the right. After cutting down a tree, the wood obtained can be made into many different objects, thus "make" became an extended meaning. 制 furthermore had more extended meaning.

Over time, 制 became the definition for non-tangible things that can be "made" such as "regulation", "system", and "formula". "Control" 控制 was an extended meaning for the "system" definition. Another component 衣 was added at the bottom becoming 製. This took on the meaning of "make" or "manufacture" for tangible objects such as clothes and furniture.

製 is still the standard in areas that use traditional script such as Hong Kong. In PRC, 製 was removed and 制 is reused as the meaning for make and manufacture.

https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%88%B6

Comment: Is there any consolidated list of corrupted characters? possibly in the link?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. You have to study the ancient writings to know their etymology to know what the original component is.

Comment: @user27485 On Chinese StackExchange, you can search for the tag [glyph-origin] and the word corrupt*, like so: `https://chinese.stackexchange.com/search?q=[glyph-origin]+corrupt*`. This will come up with a list of Q/A that has been asked so far for which characters have been described as having corrupted components.